# Refresh files in NERDTree?

Tags: plugin-nerdtree

How do I refresh file tree in NERDTree ?

If I use:

```
:!touch SomeNewFile
```

It is not rendered in the tree.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The NERD tree quick help is accessible from the NERD tree window by typing <kbd>?</kbd> There I read:

> " Filesystem mappings~
>   ...
>   " r: refresh cursor dir
>   " R: refresh current root

These should do what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

I use a custom map to refresh `NERDTree`:

```
nmap <Leader>r :NERDTreeFocus<cr> \| R \| <c-w><c-p>
```

Once set, <kbd>Leader</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> will do this for you:

- Switch to `NERDTree`
- Refresh the Root Node
- Switch back to the previous window

---

<sup>**Note:** My key map has a last step where it [refreshes CtrlP after refreshing NERDTree](https://github.com/sheharyarn/dotfiles/blob/master/Vim/.vimrc#L43-L44)</sup>